# Why am i getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')?

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I'm creating a cart for a ecommmerce site I'm in the price of updating the total price of the items correlating to the Quantity but im running an error?

```
function updatetotal () {
    const cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-content")[0];
    const cartBoxes = cartContent.getElementsByClassName("cart-box");
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cartBoxes.length;i++) {
        const cartBox = cartBoxes[i];
        const priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName("cart-price")[0];
        const quantityElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName("cart-quanity");
        let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerHTML.replace('$',''))
        const quantity = quantityElement.value;
        total+= price * quantity;
        document.getElementsByClassName("total-price")[0].innerText = '$' + total; 

    }
}
```

I've tried just about everything I think its a minor mistake made somewhere maybe?

Comment: If one of those `getElementsByClassName()` calls returns an empty list, then trying to read `[0]` from that list will give you that error.

Comment: Change from ```let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerHTML.replace('$',''))``` to ```let price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerHTML).toString().replace('$','')```

Comment: @Newbee that will not help with the problem reported in the question.

Comment: @Pointy A nitpick, but `[0]` is not the source of the error, it is accessing `.innerHTML` on the `undefined` which `[0]` will return. I.e. `[][0]` is `undefined`, no error; `[][0].x`, or the equivalent `undefined.x`, is an error.

Comment: @Amadan but `[0]` is what makes the left-hand side of `.innerHTML` be `undefined`.  In other words, there error means "you cannot get `.innerHTML`, or any other property, from an `undefined` object." There's nothing to be fixed about the `.innerHTML` code, in other words; the problem is that there's no element 0 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Either the elements classname are miswritten, (which is very unlikely, since you've checked it 100 times haha) or you are trying to access it before it was rendered.

1. Check if you can move the script to execute below the HTML tag that contains class="cart-box", preferably right before the < body > closing tag.
2. Try to execute updatetotal() after DOM is completely loaded:

   ```
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      updatetotal()
    });
   ```
3. In cases where the rendering of elements via Ajax occurs after the DOM is completely loaded, you can try the following trick: write a function that checks if the element is present, if not you wait a few seconds and call the function again recursively:

   ```
    let cartBoxes //Global

    const delay = ms => new Promise(res => (setTimeout(res, ms)));

    async function waitForCartBoxes() {
        cartBoxes = cartContent.getElementsByClassName("cart-box");
        if (cartBoxes.length == 0) { //Not found - wait 500ms and try again.
            await delay(500);
            waitForCartBoxes();
            return
        }
    }
   ```

The last solution is definitely not the best one, but gets the job done.

Comment: No, the last solution is definitely not the best one :) It would be best if the AJAX code triggered the function in its success handler; but if you can't do that for some reason, and just have to check if an element was updated, you can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead of periodically checking.

Comment: Thanks, @Matheus going to try that solution out.

Comment: @lonely555 You are welcome! Let us know if it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Your html code? If your Javascript code wrote before html, at that time, the element that you search is not "exist" (Javascript cannot read the html code after it). You should move Javascript to the end of `<body>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).